# how to replace alphabetic values to another column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I got the following df

| housenumber | housenumber_extra |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | a |
| 55a | a |
| 55-4 | -4 |
| 3455 C |  |

How can i get the following df

| housenumber | housenumber_extra |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | A |
| 55 | A |
| 55 | -4 |
| 3455 | C |

I filtered the alphabetic values from it with replace function. And then using the update function but its not working. Does someone know a better way

```
housenumber = df['huisnummer'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z.,-/]', '')

df.set_index('serial', inplace=True)
df.update(huisnummer)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # to recover the initial structure
```

Comment: [Am I right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459401/16343464) to think that you actually only need the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.str.extract`:

```
df['housenumber_extra'] = df['housenumber'].str.extract(r'\d+([^\d].+)$')[0].str.strip().fillna(df['housenumber_extra']).str.upper()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  housenumber housenumber_extra
0           1               NaN
1           2                 A
2         55a                 A
3        55-4                -4
4      3455 C                 C
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're actually not using the second column and can extract all info directly from the first column:

```
df[['housenumber', 'housenumber_extra']] = (df['housenumber']
                                           .str.extract('(\d+)\W*(\w*)')
                                           .replace({1: str.upper})
                                           )
```

output:

```
  housenumber housenumber_extra
0           1                  
1           2                  
2          55                 a
3          55                 4
4        3455                 C
```

Or even without assignment using named capturing groups:

```
(df['housenumber']
 .str.extract('(?P<housenumber>\d+)\W*(?P<housenumber_extra>\w*)')
 .replace({'housenumber_extra': str.upper})
)
```

Comment: Nice, but `housenumber_extra` needs to be uppercase...

Comment: @richardec easy enough, see update ;)

Comment: Wow, another sharp trick! `.replace` with a function!?

Comment: But in record 2 Housenumber_extra must be 'A' instead of NaN